# How do I add default system-ui font in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I used Styled components, and added  `font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, Noto Sans, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji, Segoe UI Symbol, Noto Color Emoji;` code to Global Styles file to apply the default system-ui font.

How do I use this default font with the new next/font?
I think there will be a bit of a delay in the loading method from Global Styles, so I would like to move on to the new next/font method.

Please tell me how to apply the default system-ui to next/font.

Comment: You don't need next/font for this. Simply global styles would work. next/font is needed for non-local fonts that need to be optimized and bundled. system-ui should automatically load without any delay or network request.

Comment: So, won’t there be a delay even with my Global styles settings method? I only considered next/font so that the font would not be delayed.